# Wordpress multisite causing Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET): Unknown error

Tags: php, apache, wordpress, .htaccess

We have just installed WordPress 3.0.1 and everything worked fine. However, as soon as we started to install the multisite functionality by following this [tutorial](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network), things started to go wrong. At the end of step 5, the tutorial has you update your wp-config.php file and .htaccess file. Once we made the reccommended changes to these files, uploaded them back to the server and tried to re-log in, no pages would serve up anymore. We now get the following error for ALL pages in the blog:

```
Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET): Unknown error.
```

Any ideas? Here are the code changes we made (following the sub-folder setup):

wp-config.php

```
define( 'MULTISITE', true );
define( 'SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false );
$base = '/';
define( 'DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'oursite.com' );
define( 'PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/' );
define( 'SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
define( 'BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
```

.htaccces file (in wordpress root directory)

```
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule  ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule  ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

On wp.config, insert:

```
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
```

Just do it!